# recibir un dato de tipo fecha html y php

Tags: php, html

El siguiente es un campo de una pagina web que estoy desarrollando, a lo cual pido al usuario la fecha de nacimiento

```
Fecha nacimiento <input type="date" name="FECHA_NAC"><br/>
```

Por medio de la anterior linea, debo guardar este dato en una base de datos en mysql y no se como recibir un dato de tipo date, si es con el metodo POST o con otro, ya que el resto de datos como por ejemplo cedula, lo acepta de esta forma

```
$CEDULA =$_POST['CEDULA'];
```

pero al intentarlo de la misma forma con el dato de fecha de nacimiento me sale este error

```
Notice: Undefined index: FECHA_NAC in C:\xampp2\htdocs\avanzada\registro.php on line 38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo de esta manera:

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['FECHA_NAC']));
echo $fecha;
```

La función [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) convierte una descripción de fecha/hora textual en Inglés a una fecha Unix